# blinking jquery effect doesn't work on firefox

Tags: jquery

This code works with chrome, not with firefox

```
$('#selectboardmodel').each(function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    setInterval(function() {
        if (elem.css('visibility') == 'hidden') {
            elem.css('visibility', 'visible');
        } else {
            elem.css('visibility', 'hidden');
        }    
    }, 500);
});
```

The HTML is :

```
<span id="selectboardmodel">Select</span>
```

Can you help me figure it out ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your code to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so that we can see?

Comment: why would you use an each function on an ID? Normally there should be only 1 object with that ID ...

Comment: looks fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/NjcJr/2/  .. since you have Id there will be only one element

Comment: clear your FF cache and try again

Comment: @KristofFeys yes indeed, but I don't know what to use for an id object instead of .each

Comment: just remove it ... or use $(document).ready(); ... but the each is useless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code to

```
                $('#selectboardmodel').each(function() {
                    var intID;
                    intID = setInterval ( RepeatCall, 1500 );
                    function RepeatCall() {
                        $("#selectboardmodel").fadeOut(500).fadeIn(1000);
                    }
                    $("#chosenone").change(function(){
                        $("#selectboardmodel").stop().fadeIn(100);
                        clearInterval(intID);      
                    });
                });
```

and now I obtain a nice blink and it works on Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You code works fine for me in Chrome and Firefox - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fKeS3)

Not sure why you are using the `.each` function on an ID as IDs should be unique so there should be only one! A better way to achieve this functionality might be:

JS

```
(function () {
    var elem = $('#selectboardmodel'),
        t = setInterval(function () {
            elem.toggleClass("hidden");
        }, 500);
})();
```

CSS

```
.hidden
{
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

Revised [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fKeS3/1/)